# Can the traditional remote desktop client be accessed in Windows RT?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8, microsoft-surface

As mentioned in another question, [I've been unable to connect through the Remote Desktop metro app](https://superuser.com/questions/491266/remote-desktop-app-cant-connect-through-vpn-or-through-rdp-load-balancer) to some computers, in particular those requiring VPN access or load balancers.

I'm considering purchasing a Microsoft Surface RT, but given that the app store hasn't matured significantly yet and some niche software will likely never be ported to the Modern UI, I *must* have acess to remote systems somehow. Until Citrix fixes the receiver app for Windows 8, I'm stuck using remote desktop. Which doesn't work.

I've heard that Windows RT comes with some of the Microsoft desktop programs built in, like Microsoft Office and File Explorer. Is the "normal" Remote Desktop Connection program available in Windows RT, and if so, is it 100% compatible with previous versions? I've seen comments online saying that searching for `mstsc` on the search menu brings it up, but I'd like to see some sort of official source or screenshot verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original remote desktop certainly works the same way it did before supporting remote apps and what not.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Windows RT remote desktop screenshot]

Comment: Perfect! There's the info I needed. Thanks for checking.

Comment: There's also a Remote Desktop app from Micrsoft in the Store. It seems to support most things as well.

Comment: that's true, although as mentioned in the first line of my question, I've had trouble getting the Remote Desktop app to work with certain servers and VPN connections.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned/shown above, Surface RT does have 'traditional' RDP with full support similar to Win 7. RD Gateway support is also present.

Surface RT also supports RemoteApp where remote application windows are delivered to the local desktop (application session virtualization).

To add to a comment about gaining access to shortcuts, there's a Power User hotkey - Win+X - that provides quick access to Command Prompt, Command Prompt (Administrator) and others.

I've found that the VPN for PPTP works as expected. I haven't tested other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to c:\windows\systen32, you can pull a shortcut out onto the desktop for mstsc.exe.  that is remote desktop and it works just like you would expect.  no app needed.  btw, you can also pull cmd.exe shortcut out onto the desktop for a command prompt.

Comment: Well you mispelled system32, but i really found this comment usefull since what i needed was the original "desktop" rdc application.

Answer (score -1):

I found one other remote desktop app in the Store: [Splashtop Remote Desktop](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/a3d281b1-fff3-4319-9c5a-717cade64658). There is also TeamViewer, but that's probably not what you want. If you have Windows 8 installed you could give it a try with Splashtop. Although I have personally been able to use the Metro Remote Desktop app to connect through a VPN.

Comment: This app doesn't work with Remote Desktop Protocol, it requires their own proprietary server to be installed. That does me no good - I have to access remote systems that I can't install my own software on.

Comment: Sorry :( I'm hoping they add more options to the metro version as well